# vue bind checkbox checked to result of function and passing it a value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My template looks something like this:

```
<label >
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="facet.name" 
    :value="term.term"
    :checked="isChecked(facet.name)"
    v-on:change="filerChange($event, facet.name)"
  >
    {{term.term}} <span class="facet-count">({{term.count}})</span>
</label>
```

In my script I have the method:

```
isChecked(name) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
  return this.$route.query.hasOwnProperty(name);
},
```

This works but only on initial render, when I check or uncheck the checkbox it will not call `isChecked` again and just toggle the checkbox.

Comment: what is your problem in this code?

Comment: @JinalSomaiya It only initially sets the value. When I check or uncheck the box it won't re calculate if it's checked or not

Comment: but it call change method when you toggle checkbox.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya I think the `v-on:change` function didn't change anything that would cause a re render. Now that the `v-on:change` did change something (router push) it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods written with args in the template are called during render. To avoid that use an arrow function that will call your target method.

```
<label >
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="facet.name" 
    :value="term.term"
    :checked="() => isChecked(facet.name)"
    v-on:change="() => filerChange($event, facet.name)"
  >
    {{term.term}} <span class="facet-count">({{term.count}})</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I think the `v-on:change` function didn't change anything that would cause a re render. Now that the `v-on:change` did change something (router push) it works as expected.